# Derivative with physics

Tags: calculus, physics

The position $s$ at time $t$ of a moving object is given by $$s(t)=\frac{1}{3}t^3-\frac{3}{2}t^2$$ Assume the object moves in a straight line and that $t$ is greater or equal to zero. Measure $s$ in inches and $t$ in seconds.

When is the object speeding up? When is is the object slowing down?

Comment: 'Speeding up' means positive acceleration and 'slowing down' means negative acceleration. So find the second derivative of $s$...

Answer (score 2):

The velocity at time $t$ is $t^2-3t$. This is positive if $t\gt 3$ and negative if $0\lt t\lt 3$.

The **speed** is $3t-t^2$ for $0\lt t\lt 3$ and $t^2-3t$ for $t\gt 3$.

We interpret "speeding up" as meaning that the speed is increasing. In the interval from $0$ to $3$, the derivative of the speed is $3-2t$. This is positive if $0\lt t\lt \frac{3}{2}$.

For $t\gt 3$ the derivative of the speed is $2t-3$, which is positive for all $t\ge 3$.

Thus the particle is speeding up in the interval $0\lt t\lt \frac{3}{2}$ and also in the interval $3\le t\lt \infty$.

Comment: The distinction between velocity and speed is new to me, does it really mean something different in English?

Comment: Yes it does, the speed in mathematical English is the absolute value of the velocity. A physicist would also make the distinction.

Comment: Andre, you and the above posters disagree

Comment: Cool, there is indeed no German version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed

Comment: @Timothy: If this were a North American first year calculus question, I would be quite certain about the interpretation I took. But my German is not good.

Comment: Velocity implies a magnitude and direction. Speed is just the magnitude. Hence, velocity is a vector quantity while speed is a scalar. $$ v = |\textbf{v}| $$ 

Of course since this is in one dimension, velocity can only be pointing in the positive and negative direction so you can simplify speed as the absolute value. But this is not always true. Once you do physics in higher dimensions you have to be careful with this.

Answer (score 1):

The instantaneous velocity is the derivative

$$v(t) = \frac{ds}{dt} = t^2 - 3t$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: i solved for velocity and acceleration correctly, this was on my test. I read in the calculus textbook that a particle speeds up when velocity and acceleration are both positive or both negative and the particle slows down when their signs are different.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT(to be clearer)

You have to look for intervals where both the velocity and the acceleration are pointing towards the same direction. To do so:

Find the first derivative of $s(t)=\dfrac{t^3}{3}-\dfrac{3t^2}{2}$ to find critical points. Separate the intervals in positive and negative ones given these critical points. Do the same with the second derivative. Then: if the velocity and acceleration are both positive or negative, then select that interval as the one in which the objetct speeds up.

**Warning!**: Please don't confuse positive velocity with speeding up. Only the acceleration will tell you if the object is slowing down or speeding up.

[image]

*Figure*: $|v(t)|$ from which it can be seen that there is an interval where the object actually slows down.

Comment: so it is speeding up when acceleration is positive and slowing down when acceleration is negative?

Comment: Exactly!${}{}{}$

Comment: Andre Nicholas below disagrees!

Comment: He has a point in saying that speed is the absolute value of the velocity (however if you sketch the graph of $|v(t)|$ you can see that it does slow down during a certain interval).

Comment: So, he is telling us: consider that the speed is the absolute value of the velocity. I have to add that if you define "speed up" as increasing speed (no matter what direction), then you must look for intervals where the velocity is positive AND the acceleration is positive, and also where the velocity is negative AND the acceleration is negative.

Comment: You're welcome.